# React Native 0.41 : navigator.push doesn't work

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, navigator

Android device 4.4.4, ReactNative 0.41.

```
class MyScene extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Current Scene: {this.props.title}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onForward}>
      <Text>Tap me to load the next scene</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onBack}>
      <Text>Tap me to go back</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
    )
  }
}


class CounterApp extends Component{


  render(){
    return (
      <Navigator
       initialRoute={{ title: 'My Initial Scene', index: 0 }}
       renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
      <MyScene
        title={route.title}

        // Function to call when a new scene should be displayed
        onForward={() => {
          const nextIndex = route.index + 1;
          navigator.push({
            title: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
            index: nextIndex,
          });
        }}

        // Function to call to go back to the previous scene
        onBack={() => {
          if (route.index > 0) {
            navigator.pop();
          }
        }}
      />
    }
  />
    )
  }

}
```

So the problem is: I can change scenes using `navigator.replace({...})`, but when I am clicking on button with onPress={`() => navigator.push({...})`} with same data, it just stops working. No answer from app, the only way to interact is close it XD. All code have been taken from [Official documentation tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.41/docs/using-navigators.html)

Comment: It doesn't throw any warnings or errors? It just stays at the first screen and becomes unresponsive?

Comment: I've tried to run your code, in my case it worked. RN 0.41.2

Comment: Yes, it just stays at first screen and becomes unresponsive. At first click button reacts to click, but after this click it becomes unresponsive and button doesnt do anything

Comment: I found some solution to problem: navigator.push only works without remote Chrome debugging(lol). If i turn off debugging, it works. So i think i will automatically replace .push with .replace when debugging. Or i just dont know [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4933)